# Coding complex integration and limits in R

Tags: r, math, complex-numbers

I am trying to integrate an complex logarithm function in R, but I am not sure how to define it.

Also when I write say `x*i` I get i is not defined ... but it is square root of opposite 1, isn't it? If I write say `5i` I get no problem but `5*i` gives error.

I define with some numbers x and y. In general, following code gives me an error

```
fun <- function(x + y*i){1/(x + y*i)}

integrate(fun,5+0i,10+0i)
```

Following code works

```
lower = 5

upper = 10

z <- complex(real = x, imaginary = y)

fun <- function(z){1/z}

integrate(fun,lower,upper)
```

But how do calculate contour integrals? This is double integral, really, and I have no idea how to implement it here.

More importantly, I want to take a right hand limit (i.e. lim Y -> 0+) involving a complex logarithm, equal to (1), where Y decreases to 0 while X is fixed. Here, I could not define my complex function and variable without error.

Comment: It's a bit hidden, but `?NumericConstants`  will explain the syntax, which is `45i` , i.e. follow a number with "i" to make it imaginary.  `i` by itself is an object.  Now: a complex integration is essentially a double integral, which is why `integrate` barfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex integration is integration along a path.
You can parametrize the path, by arc length, i.e., using a real interval.
(The result can actually depend on the path.)

One would expect to be able to compute 
the integral of `1/z` along a straight line between `-2-1i` and `2-1i`
as follows (note the use of `1i` rather than `i`).

```
f <- function(s) {
  z <- s-1i
  1/z
}
integrate( f, -2, 2 ) # Fails
```

But `integrate` only works with real numbers.
You need to compute separately the real and imaginary parts.

```
integrate( function(s) Re(f(s)), -2, 2 )$value +
1i * integrate( function(s) Im(f(s)), -2, 2 )$value
# [1] 0+2.214297i
```

Comment: @GuidoJorg  I suspect you'll be happier after reading introductory tutorials on `R`.  Then it'll be clear that `myfunction()$value` returns the list element `$value` from the object that `myfunction` creates.

Answer (score 3):

There are functions in packages `elliptic` and `pracma` to compute a complex integral along a path directly, i.e. they do the splitting for you. For instance,

```
f <- function(z) 1/z  # the complex function
P <- c(-2-1i, 2-1i)   # straight line between two points

require(pracma)
cintegral(f, P)       # complex integral along path P
## [1] 0+2.214297i
```

and similar for functions `integral.contour()` or `integral.segment()` in package `elliptic`. To integrate function `f` around the origin, do

```
P <- c(-1i, 1, 1i, -1, -1i)  # rectangle around 0
cintegral(f, P)
## [1] 0+6.283185i
```

and the same integral value `2*pi*1i` for a circle around the origin.

Answer (score 1):

As @Carl Withhoft mentioned, complex integration is beyond what `integrate` can do. In the meantime, this is how you would obtain a complex number given the real and imaginary parts:

```
x <- 2
y <- 4

z <- complex(real=x, im=y)
# or
z <- x + y*1i
```

And if you want a function of a complex number:

```
fun <- function(z) 1/z
fun(z)  # 0.1 - 0.2i
```